# AngularJS passing ng-model as filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-model

So to put things in perceptive I got this code that searches streams (Json) and filter is game,and it filters it by games and it all works fine.

```js
var app = angular.module('myStream', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams").then(function(response) {
    $scope.myName = response.data.streams;
    $scope.link = "http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=";
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid"  ng-controller="customersCtrl3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->
   <div id="searchBoxes">
      Search by game: <input type="text" ng-model="search.game">
   Search by language: <input type="text" ng-model="search.channel.language">
   </div>
    </div>
 
<div  ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="customersCtrl"  class="video">
     <iframe ng-repeat="x in myName | filter:search "
  src="{{link+x.channel.name| trustThisUrl}}"
        height="250" 
        width="320" 
        frameborder="1" 
  autoplay="false"
  preload="no"
        scrolling="no"
        allowfullscreen="true">
    </iframe>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to know how to do same thing(this where is ng-model="search.game") and pass it in filter.
I tried something like this with select but it doesn't work,just can't find way to pass it same like this above.I know that above is solved problem and it works,but I need to make it this way or similiar,games categorization and when one is selected it passes it in filter and shows streams with only that game.Thank you.

```html
<div ng-controller="customersCtrl4">
      <p>selected item is : {{selectedItem}}</p>
      <select ng-model="selectedItem.game">
        <option ng-repeat="x in myGames" value="{{x.game.name}}">{{x.game.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
 <div ng-controller="customersCtrl" sytle="color:white">
<ul ng-repeat="x in myName | filter:selectedItem">
<li> <a ng-href="{{x.channel.url}}" target="_blank">{{x.channel.name}}</a>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I had a hard time understanding your issue, but one thing I can tell you is that using `ng-repeat` on an `<option>` element doesn't allow 2-way binding.  If you are expecting a pre-selected option based on the model value, you will need to use `ng-options` on the `<select>`

Comment: Well I just want to do this thing with model and filter <input type="text" ng-model="search.game"> <iframe ng-repeat="x in myName | filter:search ">  For select,so it will work with ng-options?

Comment: Can you build this in jsfiddle/jsbin/plunkr so that I can address the problem in working code?  I think it's probably just a matter of your filter's expression

Comment: Well I am trying to put it but it doesn't work on those sites,but in local works.

Comment: Please try to provide an example in plunkr or something similar. It's hard to understand exactly what you want from your question.